# Query Block to insert into the more than 5 Tables with Similar Name(table1, Table 2) and same Column names in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

```
`IN_Table_Num Number:=4;
IF IN_Table_Num >3 and IN_Table_Num <100 Then 
Insert Into Table||IN_Table_Num
()Values()
End IF;`
```

I have table Names Like Table1, Table2 till Table9 with same column names (ID, Name, priority)
Now I want to insert/update into the tables based upon the Number being passed. For example if passed number is 2, it should insert or update the data into Table2 and if number is 3 it should be insert/updated into Table3. Please answer the same

I want to concatenate Table Name to generate Table4 to 9 and insert as IN_Table_Num is passed. The column name are same all over the Table4 to Table9

Please explain

Please help

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried so far? Or is it you dont know how to start?

Comment: I have added the sample code plz throw some light now

Comment: I am worried about the Performance as I have heard that Dynamic queries are not a good option performance wise

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL for this purpose (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm for reference). Pretty much you build a string for your insert statement where you can make the table name by concatenating the name stub with the number, and then do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on it.

Comment: I am worried about the Performance as I have heard that Dynamic queries are not a good option performance wise

Comment: Well, if you know for sure that you have exactly 96 tables, you can get away with explicitly writing 96 inserts. Performance of the dynamic SQL is a concern only if you have other options. Is there any particular reason you cannot use Oracle partitions?